# Selecting specific row based on column value and inserting a formula

Tags: vba, excel

In the attached image containing my data i am trying to do the following :

1)To select all rows and individual cells from column I through the end(column BQ) if the value in column C = "DOSH"
2) Once i select those cells(I through BQ) for each cell i want to use a formula 
  "=R(-2)C/R(-3)C"

I started with the following code but it selects the entire row and not just column I through BQ.  I am also not sure where i should include the formula.

[image]

```
Sub SelRows()
Dim ocell As Range
Dim rng As Range

For Each ocell In Range("C:BQ")

If ocell.Value = "DOSH" Then

If rng Is Nothing Then

Set rng = ocell.Select
Else
Set rng = Union(rng, ocell.EntireRow)
End If
End If
Next

If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Select

Set rng = Nothing
Set ocell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use `Set rng = Range("I" & ocell.row)` instead of `Set rng = ocell.Select` and `Set rng = Union(rng, Range("I" & ocell.Row))` instead of `Set rng = Union(rng, ocell.EntireRow)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this? I'm not sure about your formula so that may need adjusting. Assumed your data start in row 2.

```
Sub SelRows()

Dim ocell As Range
Dim rng As Range

For Each ocell In Range("C2", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If ocell.Value = "DOSH" Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = Range(Cells(ocell.Row, "I"), Cells(ocell.Row, "BQ"))
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, Range(Cells(ocell.Row, "I"), Cells(ocell.Row, "BQ")))
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = ""=iferror(R[-2]C/R[-3]C,"""")""
End If

Set rng = Nothing
Set ocell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: that works well. My only question is how i can avoid division error because i have values in R[-3]C zero. Can i do on error goto 0?

Comment: You can use IFERROR - amended above. This will return a blank if error results, but can be altered.